# Double clicking a file gives "debug" as second parameter?

Tags: c#, arguments

When I double click a certain file the arguments for the launched application are according to Process Explorer:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKeSoft\PCG Tools\PcgTools.exe" debug D:\Muziek\Korg\Workstations\Kronos\Sounds and Templates_Commercial\KRS\KRS-03\KRS-03.PCG

How come there is debug as second argument?

Comment: Have you checked the file association for that file type in the registry? Double click executes an arbitrary command line with a placeholder for the filename. If that string is `PcgTools.exe debug %1` you'll get your observed behavior.

Comment: @CodesInChaos you are completely right ... I have added it to save myself some troubles for command line arguments ... If you add your remark into an answer I can give it the points it deserves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File associations are set in the registry using a string describing the command line that should be executed. That string can contain arbitrary additional parameters in addition to the `%1` placeholder for the filename.

If the string is something like `PcgTools.exe debug %1` you'll get a command line like the one you observed.

As Raymond notes, if you don't enclose `%1` in quotation marks, the shell will not insert them, even if the filename does contain spaces. The default command line parsing then treats that single filename as multiple parameters split by space, so you typically want to use `"%1"`.

In your case there are no `"` around the filename, so I guess your program uses `%1` is non standard command line parsing. Some (mostly older) programs behave like this, but I recommend against it for your own programs. Use `"%1"` and standard parsing for them.

Comment: Also, you will not get quotation marks around the file name parameter, which will cause problems if the file name contains spaces.