# Seeing multiple arguments in C# arguments as one for folder/name containing spaces?

Tags: c#, arguments

When I double click a certain file the arguments for the launched application are according to Process Explorer:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKeSoft\PCG Tools\PcgTools.exe" debug D:\Muziek\Korg\Workstations\Kronos\Sounds and Templates_Commercial\KRS\KRS-03\KRS-03.PCG

Is there an easy way to see the arguments containing the file name (after debug) as one string (without parsing / combining / extracting all possibilities manually)?

Reason: there can be more files (with or without spaces in them).

What I get as arguments is:

```
argument 0: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKeSoft\PCG Tools\PcgTools.exe"
argument 1: debug
argument 2: D:\Muziek\Korg\Workstations\Kronos\Sounds
argument 3: and 
argument 4: Templates\_Commercial\KRS\KRS-03\KRS-03.PCG
```

What I want is:

```
argument 0: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKeSoft\PCG Tools\PcgTools.exe"
argument 1: debug
argument 2: "D:\Muziek\Korg\Workstations\Kronos\Sounds and Templates\_Commercial\KRS\KRS-03\KRS-03.PCG"
```

i.e. I want automatic " around the strings and have them combined. It is easy in this case but when having multiple files it can be tricky.

Note: This is not the problem about the Debug parameter (see [Double clicking a file gives "debug" as second parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004869/double-clicking-a-file-gives-debug-as-second-parameter)) although the same example is used.

Comment: You've already posted that question ... [Double clicking a file gives "debug" as second parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004869/double-clicking-a-file-gives-debug-as-second-parameter)

Comment: No it is unrelated ... this one is about spaces which makes my arguments incomplete file names/folder names. It has nothing to do with the Debug as second parameter.

Comment: You need to fix the file to do this. That is the only easy way.

Comment: Are there any other possible parameters after debug? Or is that the only real possibility?

Comment: @Ryan Gates: You mean by manually checking which parts belong together (folder parts and file name parts)? Seems like a difficult task, especially when multiple arguments are selected (which all can contain spaces).

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud There can be multiple parameters and also options (but those have a dash all in front of them so I could sort those out rather easily).

Comment: No, I mean you need to fix the certain file that is building the call. That file has the necessary knowledge/context to make the right decision about using quotes.

Comment: @Ryan Gates: That 'file' is Windows 7 which opens my application with the arguments split by spaces.

Comment: Then I would enter it as [a bug for Windows 7](https://connect.microsoft.com/) such for that specific file saying that it doesn't handle arguments with spaces.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek:  This is not a duplicate, see first paragraph.

Comment: @GSerg: This is not a duplicate, see first paragraph.

Comment: @Will: This is not a duplicate, see first paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file type registration did not put quotation marks around the argument. If you want the argument quoted, you must provide the quotation marks. Windows is just following the instructions you provided.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKeSoft\PCG Tools\PcgTools.exe" debug "%1"
```

Note the quotation marks around %1.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this examples:

```
C:\development\abkcmd\abkcmd\bin\Debug>abkcmd.exe one "two parms" 3
Number of command line parameters = 3
Arg[0] = [one]
Arg[1] = [two parms]
Arg[2] = [3]


C:\development\abkcmd\abkcmd\bin\Debug>abkcmd.exe one two parms 3
Number of command line parameters = 4
Arg[0] = [one]
Arg[1] = [two]
Arg[2] = [parms]
Arg[3] = [3]


C:\development\abkcmd\abkcmd\bin\Debug>abkcmd.exe one two 'parms' 3
Number of command line parameters = 4
Arg[0] = [one]
Arg[1] = [two]
Arg[2] = ['parms']
Arg[3] = [3]
```

You can do this with this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Number of command line parameters = {0}", args.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Arg[{0}] = [{1}]", i, args[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I know but the problem is I cannot decide how the parameters are send. I know how to read them but to manually paste the correct arguments together is not trivial ... at least I hope there is some easy solution for this.